# this.props.dispatch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm unable to call dispatch function when I try to use `bindActionCreators`

**Dispatch Function not working:**

```
@connect(state => ({oPurchaseDetails: state.cart.cartItems}), dispatch => bindActionCreators({updateItem}, dispatch))
```

If I don't use `bindActionCreators`, updateItem function doesn't work.

**updateItem Function not working:**

```
@connect(state => ({oPurchaseDetails: state.cart.cartItems}), dispatch => ({updateItem, dispatch}))
```

Answer (score 5):

`connect` only inserts `this.props.dispatch` automatically if you do *not* supply a `mapDispatch` function.  Because you're using your own `mapDispatch`, you are responsible for including that in the return value.

See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-props-dispatch for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a return value to pull in the `dispatch` function.

Something like that:

```
@connect(
    // this provides the dispatch function
    (state) => {return {
        oPurchaseDetails: state.cart.cartItems
    }},
    dispatch => bindActionCreators({updateItem}, dispatch)
)
```

I hope that helps